# Open Visual Studio Code Powershell Terminal in script folder

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When I right-click a ps1 script in VSCode and open it in Powershell Terminal, the current folder is not the script folder but the project folder.

Is there a way to configure it to open in the script folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You've **configured PowerShell as the default shell** - either via command `Terminal: Select Default Shell` (on Windows) or directly via user settings `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` / `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx"` / `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux"`.
- You're trying to open a PowerShell instance by **right-clicking a file / subfolder  in the side bar's  `Explorer` view and choose `Open in Terminal`**, and you want that instance's **current location to be that file's containing folder / that subfolder**.

As of (at least) VSCode 1.17.2, **this should work by default**.

If it doesn't, **perhaps custom code in your `$PROFILE` directly or indirectly changes the current location**.

If you don't want to / cannot prevent `$PROFILE` code from changing the location, here's a **workaround** via the user settings that **explicitly sets the current location** *after* the `$PROFILE` code has run:

On **Windows**:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "/c", "powershell -noexit -command 'Set-location \"%CD%\"'" ]
```

This uses `cmd.exe` as the default shell, which then invokes PowerShell with a command that explicitly makes it change to that folder.

The workarounds for other platforms below work analogously:

On **macOS**:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [ "-l", "-c", "exec pwsh -noexit -command 'set-location \"$PWD\"'" ]
```

On **Linux**:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": [ "-c", "exec pwsh -noexit -command 'set-location \"$PWD\"'" ]
```